# Codeigniter Email Sending Error is showing fsockopen

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I want to send an email in codeigniter but error is showing, i tried all possible option but failed

```
Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Connection refused)
```

Here is my Code

```
public function mail()
{
    $config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com', 'Support');
        $this->email->to('xxx@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject('Test');
        $this->email->message('This is a test email');
    if (!$this->email->send())
{
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}
        else
        {
            echo "Email is sent!!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to display the image in the current page and open the full image when clicked as a link,

```
$this->load->helper('url'); // Load URL Helper for base_url() 
$this->load->helper('html'); // Load HTML Helper for img()

$path= base_url('img/servare.png'); // generates text: siteroot/img/servare.png 
echo anchor($path, img($path));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<a href="http://localhost/nedwara.com/img/servare.png">
   <img src="http://localhost/nedwara.com/img/servare.png" alt="">
</a>
```

Comment: jay the method you have showed it would be static i had list of post in database so when we click on title post detail page is getting open,<?= anchor("controller/method/{$method->id}",character_limiter($method->title,150)) ?> this same method i want to apply on image also